# How to create a dictionary base SingleTon?

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary base SingleTon. Some simple example like:

```
singleton = SingleTon()
singleton['a'] = 5
print(singleton['a']) #5
```

I have written a basic class:

```
class SingleTonNew():  

    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): 
        id = threading.get_ident()
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(SingleTonNew, cls).__new__({})
        return cls._instance

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        id = threading.get_ident()
        if id in self._instance:
            self._instance[id][key] = value
        else:
            self._instance[id] = {key:value}
        
    
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        id = threading.get_ident()
        return self._instance[id][item]
```

but it didn't work, how can I implement it. Thanks to everyone who answered the question.

Comment: if you want the `['a']` syntax, you should implement get/set item, not get/set attr.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Singleton(dict):
  def __new__(cls):
    if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
      cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
    return cls.instance
    
singleton1 = Singleton()
singleton2 = Singleton()

singleton1['a'] = 5
print(singleton1 is singleton2)
print(singleton2)
```

Simply inherit from `dict`.

Outputs:

```
True
{'a': 5}
```

Comment: If I need a dictionary with two layers, the first layer is the id of the thread, and the second layer is the variables I need, The dictionary represented by the thread id can be returned in different threads.How do I implement it? very grateful for your help

Answer (score 1):

I implement like this:

```
class SingleTonNew(dict):  

def __new__(cls):
    ident = threading.get_ident()
    if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
        cls._instance = super(SingleTonNew, cls).__new__(cls)
        if  ident not in cls._instance:
            cls._instance[ident] = super(SingleTonNew, cls).__new__(cls, ident)

    return cls._instance[ident]
```

I don't now if it is correct, and Is it thread-safe?

Comment: I need a dictionary with two layers, the first layer is the id of the thread, and the second layer is the variables I need, The dictionary represented by the thread id can be returned in different threads.